# Basic questions about Java syntax

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the following valid Java code.  I have two questions, which are commented in the code.

```
class C {
  C x;  //1.) why is something like x = new C(); not required here?  Does this 
        //mean x refers to this current class of C?
  int f;
  void run(boolean b, int x) {
    C y;
    y = new C(); 
    if (b) { this.bump(y,x); } //2.) Is "this" in this.bump necessary?  Likewise,
                               //this.bump(this.y,x) would be equivalent right?
    else { f = this.x.f + 1; }  
  }
  void bump(C z, int j) {
    z.f=j;
  }
  }
```

Thanks, sorry for such rudimentary questions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`1.) why is something like x = new C(); not required here?`

x is only an uninitialized reference. If you want to use it, you indeed need to assign something to it.

`2.) Is "this" in this.bump necessary?`

No. `this` refers to the current object, and since `x` is a member of the current object you do not need it in this case.

`2a) Likewise, this.bump(this.y,x) would be equivalent right?`

No. `y` is a local variable, you can not access it with `this.y`.

Comment: quick fingers yields you +1.

Comment: Its been a `low hanging fruit` :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Isn't `this.x.f` using x though?  Is it equivalent to `this.f`?

Comment: `this.x` is different from `this`, so `this.x.f` is different from `this.f`.

Comment: It could be, but it depends on what you assign to x. Genereally, as @LouisWasserman says, it is not the same, but it could be the same if you assign `this` to your `x` member. Since you currently do not assign anything to x, it is not the same for sure.

Comment: But since nothing is assigned to `x`, how do we know which class of `C` `x` is referencing?  Specifically, what `f` can we be talking about here?

Comment: this.x is that C x; that was not initialized earlier (so lets hope someone does initialize it before calling the run() method). Same goes for the f=this.x.f +1; the int f inside the x needs a value first otherwise the call of the run() method should produce a nullpointer

Comment: The code as provided would throw an exception, but perhaps `x` would be set somewhere else in the code, if this were a real piece of code...in which case, the _meaning_ of `this.x.f` is still going to be different from `this.f`.

Answer (score 3):

This one:

```
 C x;
```

declares a single field called `x` within class `C` of type `C`. The statement doesn't set any initial value of the field `x`. And it's basically the same as `C x = null`;

That one:

```
 this.bump(y,x);
```

`this` is excessive here. You would get the same with just `bump(y,x);`

`this.y` wouldn't compile in this case, because `y` is a local variable (within the method), not a field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What exactly is `this.x.f` referring to?  Since `x` isn't initialized to any value...?

Answer (score 0):

`C x;` means that you've declared a variable of type C called x. You did NOT create an instance yet which you do by calling `x = new C();`

Using the this keyword isn't necessary when calling a member method from within the same class.

`this.bump(this.y,x)` is NOT what you think it is, since y is a local variable (local to the run method) and not a class member so you'd actually get a compilation error.

Comment: If we didn't create an instance of `C x`, how is `this.x.f` legal code?

Comment: it'll compile since the compiler doesn't know that you didn't initialize it yet. If you ran the code, however, you'd get a NullPointerException when you got to this.x.f.

Answer (score 0):

1.)
`C x` doesn't reference anything here. But if you assign it, it will reference to some class of type `C`. This might be the current class, but there could also be another one referenced.
For example if `C` is a class `Person`, x could reference this persons mum, dad, friend, etc...
2.)
No, it's not needed there since theres no local variable named the same way. Its equivalent.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say `C x` doesn't reference anything here?  When we use `this.x.f`, since `C x` isn't referencing anything, how is this legal code?

Comment: At the line you commented on it, C x has a null reference. A call like `this.x.f` (the class member, not `x.f` (the local variable named the same)) would result in a NullPointerException, because you havent assigned an instance of C to your `this.x`. This will happen at runtime though.

Answer (score 0):

1) `new` allocates memory on the heap instead of the stack

2) `this` in `this.bump` is not necessary. `this.bump(this.y,x)` would not be equivalent because `class C` does not have a member variable called `y`

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) why is something like `x = new C();` not required here?

By default, the reference is `null`. It's up to the programmer to decide whether the reference needs to be initialized to point to some object.

> Does this  mean x refers to this current class of C?

Here, `x` is a reference to some instance of class `C`. The reference can be (and is) `null`.

> 2.) Is `this` in `this.bump` necessary?

No.

> Likewise, `this.bump(this.y,x)` would be equivalent right?

Yes.